# Pipe fitting identification for bathroom sink drain

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, sink

I am installing a bathroom sink and this is what I'm dealing for a drain pipe opening/receptacle. I'm *hoping* that's a drain pipe with a nut rusted onto the end of it, and hopefully with a little bit of elbow grease/WD40 I can spin it off and have access to threads that would be underneath it. Does anyone see any reason why that wouldn't be the case (maybe that's *not* a nut)?

[image]

Comment: I would tap that nut with a small hammer. Go all around the outside as well as the face. The objective is to break loose any corrosion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a nut. It's the remnants of a compression fitting, as you suspected.

That said, I don't hold out much hope that the threads are serviceable. That much corrosion may have destroyed them. You might need to cut back and sweat on a new fitting.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood. Going through the wall would be a worst case scenario. I would almost rather solder/braze an extension going into that drain pipe (from the _outside_) and then connect my p-trap to whatever I solder on there. This is all going to be covered up by a vanity; is there any reason why I couldn't solder/braze/weld something into the hole, and connect the ptrap to _that_ thing?

Comment: That's more or less what I'm suggesting. I meant to cut back behind the useless threads. Maybe you'll get lucky with them, though.

Comment: If I am (inevitably) unlucky @isherwood, what sort of pipe/fitting/material would you suggest I try soldering on?

Comment: I much prefer brass over copper, but I'm not at all sure what's readily available in that size. I don't have much experience with copper DWV plumbing.

Comment: Heck, I might resort to JB Weld. :D